# Using thread-pools managed by the application server (Glassfish)

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, threadpool, application-server

Is it possible to use directly (explicitly) the thread pools managed by Glassfish (created at `Thread Pools -> Configuration`). Are those thread pools are accessible via JNDI, or anyhow else?

Use case: monitoring / configuring thread pool executors, backed with the thread pools managed by the app server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [GlassFishWorkManagerTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jca/work/glassfish/GlassFishWorkManagerTaskExecutor.html) provided by SpringFramework.

```
GlassFishWorkManagerTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new GlassFishWorkManagerTaskExecutor();
taskExecutor.setThreadPoolName("test_threadpool");
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // do the task
  }
}
taskExecutor.execute(task);
```